# VBA - Issue setting an HTML element ID as when adding to the DOM it is not quotation mark encapsulated

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

With the following script, I create an element of a certain tag type, set the ID, and plan to then use the Document.getElementById method to operate on it.  However the following code results in the element being created as

```
<DIV id=JSBridge></DIV>
```

For valid HTML it needs to be

```
<DIV id="JSBridge"></DIV>
```

So it is missing the quotation marks.

My code so far:

```
Private Sub JS_Bridge(JsToRun As String)

    Dim body As IHTMLElement
    Dim scriptEl As IHTMLElement
    Dim controlEl As IHTMLElement

    Set body = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")(0)
    Set controlEl = WebBrowser1.Document.createElement("div")
    Set scriptEl = WebBrowser1.Document.createElement("script")
    controlEl.ID = "JSBridge"
    MsgBox controlEl.outerHTML



        scriptEl.Text = JsToRun
        body.appendChild scriptEl
        body.appendChild controlEl

End Sub
```

I have also tried:

```
controlEl.ID = """" & "JSBridge" & """"
```

However, this results in:

```
<DIV id='"JSBridge"'></DIV>
```

Which is not valid.

Comment: maybe `controlEl.ID = "'JSBridge'"` ? AFAIK, single quotes are interchangeable with double quotes in html.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, the output is <DIV id='"JSBridge"'></DIV>, the same issue..but with the single quotes on the outside this time.

Comment: How about `controlEl.ID = chr(34) & "JSBridge" & chr(34)`?

Comment: Hey, it has outcome of <DIV id='"JSBridge"'></DIV>, the same as above.

Comment: Actually when I MsgBox the controlEl it is correct, but it is the assignment to controlEl attribute ID which seems to add the single quotes.

Comment: Does it matter in this case as HTML should support the unquoted in this instance (xhtml won't)? I get it is an interesting problem though. +

Comment: Hi Qharr, it’s quite strange agreed. Basically if you set ID to anything that includes a single or double quote when the tag gets appended to the dom something encapsulates the attribute value with its opposite quotation mark. Ironicallly, it only does not do this when there is no quotation mark of either type set in the ID